# Removing PPAs to proceed with update manager seems risky

Tags: 11.10, ppa, updates, usability

After failing to update 11.10, I found a non-working PPA source, which was some guy's repository, containing software that I didn't manually install.

How do I know the consequences of deactivating this source and most likely, leaving this update at its current state for a long time?

Why can't update manager just forget about that PPA temporarily and try to update it next time?

Is there a way to save time and stop caring about OS internal components?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing an upgrade of Ubuntu from one major release to the next the update manager will deactivate all your system's PPAs before attempting an upgrade.

Your comment to Agmenor's question sort of answers your question. If the PPA is not being updated, then it's probably not useful to you and you can just remove it; or worse it's being unmaintained and can just be removed.

Comment: Nice thinking Jorge, thank you. It makes sense, but only if "not being updated {by developers, I suppose}" is the only possible reason why my system can`t reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating the PPA should normally not bring any problem. Just deactivate it in the Software Sources, the developper will probably make sure his or her PPA will work with your version of Ubuntu.

There may be some risk if it was a PPA for unstable software. To determine it, you could read the info on the PPA page or give the PPA address here so that we can determine it. In that case you may want for example to downgrade these precise programs to stable versions.

Could you also edit your question to give more details on how you think this software source was included in your other ones?

Comment: I didn`t want to complain about specific package yet, because I`m more interested in general patterns of dealing with annoyancies like that.

So you mean, that I must re-enable the ppa once in a month or so, to check whether it has been fixed? In theory it could work, but in real life, when nothing is visibly broken, probably I won`t remember to do that. And I suppose, not-updating "mysterious-somethings" can result in security holes or alike.

And, if it is a system, say, Unity, compnent, I should report a bug?